# Does SqlCE 4.0 have it's own Connection Provider in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I'm trying to create a new [SqlCE 4.0 sdf database](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx) but I'm not sure which connection provider I need to use?

I [downloaded CE4.0 from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033cfb76-5382-44fb-bc7e-b3c8174832e2) separately. ... so is there a new provider we're suppose to use? Or do we use the 3.5 provider?

Comment: Not sure, but I would suspect there is a new connection provider, given the incompatibility of many of the features between ver 3 and ver 4.

Answer (score 4):

A sample connection string would look like this:

```
<add name="integration" connectionString="Data Source=testdb.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

You should also reference the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll and the ADO.NET classes it provides.

Comment: What about in Visual Studio itself? When i goto the SERVER EXPLORER, there's only a 3.5 Provider. Is this because the 4.0 provider (for VS2010 UI) will be provided with VS2010 SP1 ?

Comment: ErikEJ has you covered. Sorry, I haven't used the visual tools. I've just been using it as a database for integration tests.